# Getting error while linking an OCCI program on AIX

Tags: c++, unix, aix

I have written one sample program for connecting Oracle in C++ using OCCI..

It is giving me a runtime error .

```
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::Mode,void*,void*(*)(void*,unsigned long),void*(*)(void*,void*,unsigned long),void(*)(void*,void*))
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .oracle::occi::Environment::terminateEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment*)
```

I have given the following command to execute it

```
g++ -o occi amrtest.cpp -Wall -I/oradata/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/rdbms/public -L/oradata/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/lib -lclntsh  -lnnz10 -locci -lclntsh  -lnnz10 -locci10
```

Can u help me in getting this error resolved ?

Comment: Hey thanks for your feedback , I checked my Oracle lib file ,
That file was missing the definitions for the createEnvironment and TerminateEnvironment.
So i downloaded the latest lib from Oracle site and then it worked properly :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not an AIX nor Oracle expert, but seems that your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (or equivalent in AIX) should include $ORACLE_HOME/lib. Check this forum entries:

```
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=2172885
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=579418&tstart=0
http://www.dbforums.com/oracle/1007236-occi-aix-oracle-9-a.html
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record - OCCI/g++ combination does not work on AIX.  I hope this would save someone's time

Comment: Please elaborate on why that is and cite sources.